# Add celery (tasker) To Django Admin panel on Search click

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using the Admin panel of django for searching.

Sometimes it can take 15 + minutes for search to finish and I get timeout (502).

But search process still exist (consuming resources).

I would like to show a progress bar waiting for task to finish when clicking:
[image]

What is the best option for me ?

NOTE:
I have 10M + records and it will be 300M+ in future.

Comment: Waiting 15 minutes only for 8k in 18k records? If you really want to solve this issue try to optimize `query` instead of putting  progress bar.  The keywords`prefetch_related` and `select_related` are will be help for that. Also keeping relation fields as readonly will help.
A reading: https://hakibenita.com/optimizing-the-django-admin-paginator

Comment: So the example is mistaken, I have 9M record.|
To filter a bolleian attribute to all record "True" values it takes 3 minutes, is it still not optimized ? I also think it is too long.

Comment: Uhh. It's too huge. **Will be better to do not use Django Admin with that data.** 

Since you check manually which mean you could not use all data. Then you may use `LIMIT` SQL word. Like for 10 page, 25 record for each `Model.objects.filter(...)[:250]`.
if user in `nth` page `Model.objects.filter(...)[n*250:(n+1)*250]`. May you need to make your own pagination bar.

Comment: I think :250 still will fetch all data just will cut it after - so it won't save time. what are dashboards alternative to manage data ?

Comment: May not reduce on DB side while using `ORDER` or `GROUP` clauses. But it will help on network and Django side. May could install `Django Debug Toolbar` and  check the results.

Comment: After everything you may need the a loading screen but that's not simple to make on Django Admin as you know.